# JPA error in merge: Password expired error if insert only

Tags: oracle, jpa, oracle11g, jpa-2.1, hibernate-jpa

We are using entitymanager merge method to either update (if existing) or insert (if not existing) records in a certain table. What happens is if it is an update, there are no errors, but if it is insert, we see the following error from our logs:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28001: the password has expired\n DSRA0010E: SQL State = 99999, Error Code = 28,001\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:938)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:480)\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655

When we checked the datasource if connection successful - we get no password expired error.

We also tried manual insert to the table via oracle sql developer tool - no error

Can anyone advise why this is happening?

Comment: Are there any triggers fired while updating this table ? Could be that the trigger connects to some externall table using another user/password, and this password has expired. Another possibility is that JPA/Hibernate is using two datasources, but it's unlikely though, since it's not easy to configure and the programmer should be aware of it.

Comment: no triggers being used

Comment: can you post the statement that causes the error? Do you maybe have a Database Link?

Comment: Are you sure it's coming form the statement that does the merge, not some other statement - on a different connection/pool it seems - which just happens to occur only when the merge does an insert? The rest of the error stack should tell you that, of course, but we can't see that or your code.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes we have a database link. I figured it could cause that but don't know how to prove it

Comment: So in that case the user that is used for the database link must have an expired password. Check this first.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli we are not using the database link. The setup is, there is another database that has a database link to this database, not vice versa.

Comment: again the same request: can you post the Statement that causes the error?

Comment: we are using the JPA library of Java to do table insert. Its using the merge method of the EntityManager